# Creating and moving files in sharepoint through powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I often have to move a large number of files from one part of sharepoint to another, and the GUI often has issues with data loss or duplication, as well as being extremely repetitive and time intensive.

Ideally I'd really like there to be a way to just navigate sharepoint files as if they were just any other files on a command line in a computer file system. Is such a thing even possible? If not, is there at least a way to cp files from one directory into another?

Things like these make it seem easy, except the file paths don't actually match up in reality to any expected path:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-move-files-using-powershell.html

When attempting to use the SPO or PNP module in powershell, the documentation is pretty unclear. Get-PNPfile either always returns file not found if I try to use /Documents/Foldername like one would think. Even if I right click and copy link and get that messy url and make sure to deal with the ampersands, it still doesn't work. For example

```
Get-PnPFile -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/team/Documents/file"
```

I would expect this to well, return an object that contains something pointing to the file, but it never works.

One possibility is that MFA is a requirement in the environment I'm using and it seems requires a flag -UseWebLogin which appears to work without errors, but it also appears to work when I mistyped the url of the team name when I used the command Connect PnPOnline, so maybe there is an issue there?

Comment: Have you tried `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com" -Interactive` yet?

Comment: Thank you! Strangely, I have to do it twice, suddenly it seems to work, at least for connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution ended up being the use of the "sync" feature which then creates an alias that can be manipulated as if it was a regular file on a machine using powershell. There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to interact with the sharepoint filesystem via command line which is bonkers.

Comment: Just a thought, I have (in the past) accessed SharePoint files by accessing them like a network file. Such as `Get-Item "\\domain.sharepoint.com\sites\team\Documents\file"`, though I did so to copy files to the local drive, I'm not sure how much SharePoint would like it if you moved files on the site that way.

Comment: I'll experiment with that next time I'm at work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First for MFA, it will be better to user `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com" -Interactive` just like the comment on your original post.

And for the file not found error, it seems you are not using the correct URL. Have a try on the site relative URL.

Here is what I have tested
[image]

Comment: It's not working for me when I try to access anything. When you use the connect-PnPOnline, what url are you using? Are you using the domain or specifying a specific site? Neither seems to work for me.

Comment: @Tyk I used the specific site url

Comment: Well thank you! For whatever reason I had to do something else to find a workaround but this was helpful.

Comment: @Tyk. Will be glad if anything I mention help you. Wish you get a better solution on this.